# How to install binaries of dependencies?

Tags: go

My Golang project depends on a few packages (i.e. https://github.com/mattes/migrate and https://github.com/joho/godotenv). I know I can `go get` or `go install` them separately, but is there a way to install all of the dependencies of a project in one shot? Ideally, I would expect `go install ./...` to put the `migrate` and `godotenv` binaries in my `$GOPATH/bin`, but it only installs the main package binary and not the binaries of the dependencies.

Comment: it would _very unsafe_ to be able to install binaries without specifying what they are.  I think being explicit when installing binaries is a good trade off between ease of use and safety.

Comment: Yes, `go install -v -u  ./...` is the command.  You say that's not happening.  can u update the question with what *is* happening?

Comment: I've updated the description (only the main package is built and added to `$GOPATH/bin`. `-u` doesn't seem to be a valid `go install` flag (are you thinking of `go get`?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for a way to install the binaries you want to call, from your local machine, automatically from a `go install ./...` of your code?

That isn't going to happen with straight up Go, unless they are listed in the same username or pattern you can type in a single go install command.  But just the two listed above are different enough that that can't happen.

Option 1) Either state to your users to call `go install` for each Dependency (this is very common).

Option 2) Or, create a bash/batch file to run them with a simple `install.sh` command in your repo.  Which, would call `go install` for all of your dependencies.  Another more UNIX/C like approach would be to create a `Makefile`, and tell your users to run `make`

Personally, I prefer option 2 as it gives you very complex control over your service or utility.  You can start simple; but, later on add tests, `go generate` commands and whatever else you like in the future - all without having to change your installation instructions `just run 'make install' and it will handle it`.  It also helps with C.I. servers that you can have a `make test` or anything to your hearts desire; but, different enough that normal users would usually run it.  All, within a single `Makefile` that you can change later.

I think my Updater script has like 25 `go get -u -v` commands.